# Como adicionar evento onclick para reproduzir áudio no canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ao clicar em uma imagem quero executar um som.

Como posso fazer essa função utilizando o evento *onclick*?

Código:

```
window.onload = function myCanvas() {
                var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                var img = document.getElementById("background");
                var img2 = document.getElementById("pedal1");

                ctx.drawImage(img,5,5);
                ctx.drawImage(img2,100,100);
}


function music()
{

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");   
    var audio1 = new Audio();
    audio1.src = "audio/samples/F.mp3";
    audio1.play();
}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta aparenta estar em inglês, será que você queria postá-la no [Stack Overflow em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com)? Se a sua intenção era mesmo de postá-la aqui no Stack Overflow em Português, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/93133/edit) e traduza a sua pergunta.

Comment: @Chun, "aparenta" é bondade sua. Ela está em inglês, rsrsrsrs

Comment: @Bruno Rhafael Poderia colocar o seu código HTML também?

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Tenta fazer assim

```
<img src="" onclick="TocarMusica()" />


function TocarMusica(){
    var audio1 = new Audio();
    audio1.src = "audio/samples/F.mp3";
    audio1.play();
}
```